# How do I download a file from a signed URL from Amazon S3 to a client machine using PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When a user clicks a link on the site, I'm trying to download a file from an Amazon S3 bucket with a signed URL through php. Here's what I have so far:

```
$client = S3Client::factory(
    array(
      'key' => 'xyz',
      'secret' => 'abc'
));

$signedUrl = $client->getObjectUrl(<bucket>, $location, '+10 minutes');
```

Now, how do I download the file using the above signed url to client machine?

Comment: Did you try using `file_get_contents` and passing the url ?

Comment: Yes I did try this and readfile()

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are having problems only in fetching the `url` and have implemented api properly, this should work

```
$client = S3Client::factory(
    array(
      'key' => 'xyz',
      'secret' => 'abc'
));

$signedUrl = $client->getObjectUrl(<bucket>, $location, '+10 minutes');
file_put_contents($fileName, file_get_contents($signedUrl));
```

Now this puts the file on your server. In order to download to client there are a couple of methods. Let me try with the most simplest

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv'); // Change mime type
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=temp.csv'); // Change filename
header('Pragma: no-cache');
echo (file_get_contents($signedUrl));
```

This would rather than saving on server serve the output to client.
Another alternative would be you send the url to javascript and download from client side.

Comment: I don't want to download the file to a server instead to a client machine via browser.

Comment: @Rumi let me add that part also

Comment: @Rumi let me know if this helps or if you need something else :)

Comment: Thanks @georoot. I did try this method earlier too. It downloads a empty jpeg file.

Comment: No, it does not. I get this message when I open the downloaded file "Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x20 0x20)". The size of the file is just fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130153/discussion-between-georoot-and-rumi).